# How to reference a Multiselect picklist field value in process builder?

Tags: salesforce, processbuilder

I am trying to copy field values from one object to other. I have a field "Cure Types" which is a multiselect picklist with values "A","B","C","D" and "E". I have this field on both "Opportunity" object and also on a custom object called "Cure". I build a process builder to copy the value from Opp to Cure whenever a new record is created in Cure.

I was unable to find the field in PB (even though they have Master-detail relationship) so I started using formula.

Crieria
NOT(ISBLANK([Cure__c].Opportunity__r.Cure_Types__C))

Action
what should be the action to copy the field value from Opp to Cure?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you misspoke I don't believe you can accomplish what you are exactly asking.

You say

> I build a process builder to copy the value from Opp to Cure whenever
>   a new record is created in Cure.

However, I am reading your question to suggest that opportunity is the child of the custom cure object?  If so, when you create the new master object there is no way that there can be a detail object associated as detail objects don't exist without the parent.

Here are a few key features about the master-detail relatinoship

> Deleting a Master Record, deletes all the detail records.
>
> A detail record cannot be created without a Master record.
>
> The permission on the detail record cannot be set. It inherits the
>   permission from the master record.
>
> The detail record also inherits the sharing rule from master records.
>
> Both the master and detail records are automatically included in the
>   report record types.

What you could do to accomplish what you are asking is an apex trigger after update that would copy the values of your multi-picklist from the detail record to the parent record.  So when you tie an opportunity to a cure, all the values would then duplicate over.